# Downloaded Music Missing from iPhone Music Library

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

I'm having a bit of a problem with my music library on my iPhone. All the downloaded songs marked as explicit have randomly gone missing from my iPhone 11 Pro. I can see that the files are still in the phone if I go to Settings > Music > Downloaded Music, but they don't actually show up in the music library itself. I don't have any restrictions enabled either.

Anyone know why this could be happening and how I can fix this?

Comment: did you go to Screen Time to turn off restrictions?

Comment: @jmh Yes, no restrictions are enabled but explicit songs still don't show up in my library.